# Find users having grants on a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.6

We grant access to users with the following

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on product_events to 'product_admin'@'%' ;
```

Now, like this there are a lot of tables, and a lot of users.

I want to find all users having any grants on a particular table

That is, given `product_events` table, I would like to get `'product_admin'@'%'`

Comment: What is the name of database `product_events` resides in ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA You can assume `product-db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This messy query should give you every user that can access `product_db.product_events`

```
SELECT user,host,'Global' Level FROM mysql.user WHERE
select_priv='Y' OR insert_priv='Y' OR update_priv='Y' OR delete_priv='Y'
UNION
SELECT user,host,'DB' FROM mysql.db
WHERE db='product_db' AND
(select_priv='Y' OR insert_priv='Y' OR update_priv='Y' OR delete_priv='Y')
UNION
SELECT user,host,'Table' FROM mysql.tables_priv
WHERE db='product_db' AND table_name='product_events';
```

If you are looking for users with all four(4) permissions (`SELECT`,`INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE` grants), then use this (basically using `AND` instead of `OR`)

```
SELECT user,host,'Global' Level FROM mysql.user WHERE
select_priv='Y' AND insert_priv='Y' AND update_priv='Y' AND delete_priv='Y'
UNION
SELECT user,host,'DB' FROM mysql.db
WHERE db='product_db' AND
(select_priv='Y' AND insert_priv='Y' AND update_priv='Y' AND delete_priv='Y')
UNION
SELECT user,host,'Table' FROM mysql.tables_priv
WHERE db='product_db' AND table_name='product_events';
```

NOTE : Table level privileges are even more messier to check since the grants are listed as a set rather than as individual columns

```
mysql> desc mysql.tables_priv;
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type                                                                                                                              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Host        | char(60)                                                                                                                          | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Db          | char(64)                                                                                                                          | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| User        | char(16)                                                                                                                          | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Table_name  | char(64)                                                                                                                          | NO   | PRI |                   |                             |
| Grantor     | char(77)                                                                                                                          | NO   | MUL |                   |                             |
| Timestamp   | timestamp                                                                                                                         | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| Table_priv  | set('Select','Insert','Update','Delete','Create','Drop','Grant','References','Index','Alter','Create View','Show view','Trigger') | NO   |     |                   |                             |
| Column_priv | set('Select','Insert','Update','References')                                                                                      | NO   |     |                   |                             |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This works.. But could this somehow be improved to include all privileges as I had to look up all privileges in `mysql.db` table and `mysql.user` table and mention each one with an `OR`.

Comment: Each table has a different level with a different set of columns per table. You specified the grants, so my answer has them. If you need more grants to check, simply add those grants to the WHERE clauses. Don't worry about searching. Grant tables are usually small.